# Java wont Integer.parseInt(string)

Tags: android, string-parsing

This is my site: http://daniandroid.honor.es/getAllCustomers.php
when you visit the site, you get a simple text "500".

OK.

```
 final ourHTTP hi = new ourHTTP();

        out_string = hi.getWebPage("http://daniandroid.honor.es/getAllCustomers.php");
```

getWebPage returns the string(content).

```
 int veriff = Integer.parseInt(out_string);

         if(veriff>1)
         {
             final_form.setText("ya");
         }
```

**final_form** is a **TextView** on my xml file (**activity_second.xml**)

**Application will crash.**
ERROR:

```
at com.android.interval.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "500"
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
```

If I replace the out_string with this

```
out_string= "500";
```

everything is good.

My **getAllCustomers.php** files contains (source):

```
<?php
echo"500";
?>
```

Here is also the method to get the content.

```
public String getWebPage(String adress)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String response = null;


    try{
        URI uri = new URI(adress);
        httpGet.setURI(uri);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);


        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        int inChar;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        while((inChar = reader.read()) != -1){

            stringBuffer.append((char)inChar);
        }

        response = stringBuffer.toString();

    }catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        Log.e(adress, "error");
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(response, "error");
        //
    }catch(URISyntaxException e)
    {
        Log.e(response, "error"); 
    }

    return response;
    }
```

Comment: Are you perhaps getting ""500"" returned from the PHP file instead of an expected String literal?

Comment: if you visit the site it will appear 500, also if you view source of page it will appear 500

Comment: Try `Integer.parseInt(out_string.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));`. I think your HTTP lib passes some non-decimal chars along with the output.

Comment: life saver. IT WORKED. THANKS

Comment: @DaniSteptu You are Welcome. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

I think your HTTP lib passes some non-decimal chars along with the output. Try this:

```
int veriff = Integer.parseInt(out_string.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
```

Where `[\\D]` is a regex denote any non-decimal character.

Comment: Yupp.. Nice catch..  +1. Need to handle junk characters also.

Answer (score 1):

May be possible your response contains `""` internally in String, Just replace `""`

So do it like,

```
out_string = hi.getWebPage("http://daniandroid.honor.es/getAllCustomers.php");

if(out_string.contains("\"")) // change according to your response, if it contains other charcter
{
 out_string = out_string.replace("\"", "")
}

try
{
 int veriff = Integer.parseInt(out_string);

 if(veriff>1)
 {
  final_form.setText("ya");
 } 
}catch(NumberFormatException ex)
{
   // Handle exception
}
```

I would suggest you to handle Exception also, May be if you have other invalid character in your resposnse..

Comment: @Aakash - Than what is the reason? Before do downvote just read question carefully, OP get response with 500..

Answer (score 0):

For the version of Java you are running against examine the code.
java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)

Crudely using Firebug and examining the response
I see "ï»¿500" which is certainly more than the "500" I would have expected.